# Password encryption at client side for html servlet

Tags: javascript, html, servlet-3.0

I have a webapp using the tomcat base. The webpages are made solely using HTML5 technology and no jsp and spring.

I have a register user and login page, which is directed to a login servlet to validate the user credentials. I'm not using a HTML form in the `registerUser` page and  `login html`. I am just using a simple HTML table to take the input.

I need to secure my password at the HTML before sending it to servlet by using either using JavaScript or jQuery. I don't want my password to be hacked while sending data by post request to servlet.

Comment: Use https instead of http

Comment: Don't. Seriously, don't. JavaScript is a terrible tool to use for this (and jQuery is a JS library, not an alternative to the language). If you want to protect data as it is sent over HTTP then use HTTPS.

Comment: Do you mean 'hashing' instead of 'encryption'?

Comment: If the man in the middle, can only listen to users' data, this can be effective, but one who can listen to it probably can also alter it, and then he can easily skip your encryption script.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, use HTTPS. It protects you against much more than any alternative 'client-side' solution could possibly achieve.

If you don't use HTTPS, you are not protected against man-in-the-middle attacks. Which means that an attacker could intercept your website while it is being delivered to a client and remove any client-side encryption / hashing / protection before sending it to the victim.

Which in turn means that no matter what you attempt at the client side (password hashing, asymmetric encryption, shared secrets, signatures) will basically just be 'security by obscurity', nothing more.

Answer (score -1):

You should configure the Tomcat server for HTTPS. Any encryption technique that you use in Javascrpt would be revealed in the source code making it useless.

You can find detailed instructions on how to configure HTTPS here:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

Comment: Can someone help me more with configuring https url

Comment: @SnehaSharma I do think my answer was useful. In the configuration instructions I point out, there is a Quick Start section which is quite clear on how to proceed. If you have any difficulty in following the instructions I can help you.